# Copy struct from its boxing into allocated memory?

Tags: c#, memory, struct

### Background

Lets say i have a struct.  Lets also pretend that we dont know its type. Thats why we have it boxed and we cant unbox it.

```
public struct Player{
   public float hp;
   public float maxHP;
}

var boxedPlayer = (object)new Player();
var typeSize = typeof(Player);
var ourAllocatedMemoryPTR = (byte*)someAllocCall();

// Copy the object into the new memory
var objHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(boxedPlayer , GCHandleType.Pinned);
var adress = objHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
var ptr = adress.ToPointer();
Buffer.MemoryCopy(ptr, ourAllocatedMemoryPTR, typeSize, typeSize);
objHandle.Free();
```

As far as i know a boxed struct... is not the same size as the struct itself... because it gets boxed and managed. So there some bytes at the head or the tail to define it as an object, a boxed struct. So the example above copies the whole boxed struct into the memory. As far as i know. Which is not what we want.

### The question

Is it possible to copy just the struct inside the box into the allocated memory ? Our new allocated memory should just store the struct, not a boxed one.
I thought it probably possible by cutting the struct out of the its box ? Cutting of the part or the head/tail that defines it as a box during copy ?

Is this possible ? How exactly does a struct gets boxed ? How many bytes are added before and after it ? How does it look like in memory ?

Glad for any help ! Thanks :)

Comment: It seems you have quite some code already. Why not run the code and have a look at the memory in the debugger?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Havent found a way to do that with unity yet :/ But i assume that it only copies the boxed struct. It would make sense. Or what do you think ?

Comment: What about [`Marshal.StructureToPtr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.structuretoptr?view=net-5.0) which copies only the unboxed part? What exactly are you trying to do, why do you need the struct in unmanaged memory?

Comment: @Charlieface If i would explain everything... i could hand in a whole book. Is Marshal.StructureToPtr able to copy a boxed struct ? Thats the point... to cut out the struct from its boxing and copy only the struct... without knowing its type during compile time ^^

Comment: But it looks promising... It actually says that the object needs to be some sort of struct which is actually pretty promising

Comment: You don't need to explain everything, just what you are trying to do here. Do you have a pre-existing buffer to copy into (seems so), how do you allocate enough space (your current code obviously doesn't work, I suggest you use `Marshal.SizeOf` which is not the same as `sizeof`), are you calling a `DllImport` (then just use the standard marshaller)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Do not use internals

The exact internal layout is subject to change. Methods like [GCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.addrofpinnedobject?view=net-5.0) are designed to give you a pointer to the object's data, not to some internal stuff like headers, method table or padding bytes. So, just use those methods, do not do the math yourself.

> Retrieves the address of **object data** in a Pinned handle.

<sub>emphasis mine</sub>

#### But it's interesting anyway

At the time of writing (and several years before), a .NET object in memory has the following layout:

- -pointersize: header
- 0: method table (type of the object)
- +pointersize: object data

You can see that with the following code. I have simplified the fields a bit, so that we can see patterns easier than with a `float`.

```
public struct Player
{
    public int hp ;
    public int maxHP;
}
class Program
{
    static unsafe void Main()
    {
        var player = new Player();
        player.hp = 0xAABB;
        player.maxHP = 0xCCDD;

        var boxedPlayer = (object) player;
        lock (boxedPlayer)
        {
            Console.ReadLine(); // Put a breakpoint here
        }
    }
}
```

In 32 Bit, the memory layout (Debug/Windows/Memory) is:

[image: 64 bit memory layout]

64 Bit memory layout:

[image: 64 bit memory layout]

- dark blue: object header, containing 0x00000001 because the object is locked
- violet: method table, defining the type (`Player`)
- green: data of the object, `hp` here
- light blue: data of the object, `maxHp` here

#### The copying process

If you now continue with

```
var ourAllocatedMemoryPTR = (byte*) Marshal.AllocHGlobal(1024);
var objHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(boxedPlayer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
var adress = objHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
var ptr = adress.ToPointer();
Buffer.MemoryCopy(ptr, ourAllocatedMemoryPTR, sizeof(Player), sizeof(Player));
```

you'll see that `ptr` points to 0x04a2a770, which is 0x04ECA76C + 4 (just where the data begins). `sizeof(Player)` is 8, which is for the two 4-byte `int`s.

Memory of `ourAllocatedMemoryPTR`  before and after `Buffer.MemoryCopy()` :

[image: Native memory before and after]

#### Strange debuggers

In a debugger like WinDbg, you get the following results for 32 bit:

```
0:009> dd 0486a76c-4 L4
0486a768  00000001 06d68ff8 0000aabb 0000ccdd
^Address  ^Header  ^MT      ^hp      ^maxHP

0:009> ? aabb
Evaluate expression: 43707 = 0000aabb
0:009> ? ccdd
Evaluate expression: 52445 = 0000ccdd

0:009> !do 0486a76c
Name:        BoxedStructInMemory.Player
MethodTable: 06d68ff8
EEClass:     06d58ee4
Size:        16(0x10) bytes
File:        C:\Users\...\BoxedStructInMemory.dll
Fields:
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
0484697c  4000001        4         System.Int32  1 instance    43707 hp
0484697c  4000002        8         System.Int32  1 instance    52445 maxHP
ThinLock owner 1 (02810B18), Recursive 0
```

And for 64 bit:

```
0:009> dq 000001a3c93ead50-8 L3
000001a3`c93ead48  00000001`00000000 00007ff8`a2f22180
000001a3`c93ead58  0000ccdd`0000aabb

0:009> !do 000001a3c93ead50
Name:        BoxedStructInMemory.Player
MethodTable: 00007ff8a2f22180
EEClass:     00007ff8a2f1c5e8
Size:        24(0x18) bytes
File:        C:\Users\...\BoxedStructInMemory.dll
Fields:
              MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value Name
00007ff8a2e2b1f0  4000001        8         System.Int32  1 instance            43707 hp
00007ff8a2e2b1f0  4000002        c         System.Int32  1 instance            52445 maxHP
ThinLock owner 1 (000001A3C7899930), Recursive 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! :) Could you possible add an describtion/example on how we just copy the struct from a boxed struct into allocated memory ? Without those bytes that describe the object ?

Comment: @genaray: I'd say the rest of your code is fine for C++ CLI. For P/Invoke you should use Marshal.SizeOf<>. I'm not an expert on that subject.

Comment: Thanks ! So this is the right way we copy a structure into allocated memory ? And this wont copy the bytes from the box ? Just the raw structure ? Not an boxed one into the memory ?

Comment: It is absolutely worth pointing out that the details of how managed objects are laid out in memory is the exclusive purview of the runtime(s) and is subject to change, without managed code getting to complain. Taking a dependency on the layout as described here would be unwise; classes like `Marshal` and the various attributes exist to allow copying from managed to unmanaged memory without having to know, while things like `ref` types and `Unsafe` were added to recent versions of C#/.NET for low-level manipulation without having to copy.

Comment: @genaray Well, it copies data from the boxed one, but it only copies the data part of it, not the header and not the method table.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Thanks a lot for the detailed describtion ! :) So if it copies the data part... it actually only copied the plain struct into the allocated memory. Atleast thats what i would assume from your describtion ^^

Comment: I agree with @JeroenMostert this is unreliable. if you want to copy a whole struct to unmanaged memory, you should use `Marshal`

Comment: It's quite a lot more complex than this. You can only do this with unmanaged types (ones with no object references)

Comment: Would you mind to unaccept this. It seems I'm too wrong. Let's @John write an answer

Comment: An obvious complication here is that the "real" scenario involves dynamic types, where you can only get `obj.GetType()`, so there is no `sizeof` to rely on. There are no exposed APIs to get that size either, so one will have to write some code that assumes things that may not hold between runtimes (Mono vs CoreCLR) or even runtime versions. In some scenarios, this will be acceptable, in some - not so much.